# Make #div (%) fill out rest of wrapper div

Tags: html, css, layout

Working on a fullpage ("locked") design.

Here's what I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/5yex5nfu/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
        Nav
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        Main
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-left:50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#navigation, #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: pink;
}

#main {
    height: auto;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

I want the main div to fill out the rest of the "locked" div, with a %-value; whilst the footer and navigation hade assigned px-values.

Have seen a few solutions for my problem, but none of them seems to work. Have tried to set a %-value for every div, and it works, but as expected: The whole thing scales and messes up the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure css solution you can use calc to calculate the height of main

Example http://jsfiddle.net/5yex5nfu/2/

Just change #main height from auto to this

```
#main {
    height: calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

Read more about [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Comment: It's worth pointing out, this wont work in IE8 and below, so if you're required to support it this method won't work. (Although the calc method is a very useful addition and hopefully everyone will finally move away from IE8 soon)

Comment: Wow, did not know about calc, and it worked. Thank you for sharing! Also, the previous version of this webpage had about 2% visits from a IE browser (all 10+)

Answer (score 1):

You can use just css, with display:table propriety!

http://jsfiddle.net/Monteduro/5yex5nfu/5/

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:50px;
}

#navigation, #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: pink;
    display:table-row;
}

#main {
    height: auto;
    background: lightgreen;
    display:table-row;
}
```